# Simple DELETE query not working

Tags: php, sql, sql-delete

This is something I should be able to do but I have been trying for the last hour to see the issue here but I can't. It is a simple delete function to delete an entry through the use of a ID tag. It is getting passed through the `delete_category.php`. If it helps my sql table is called `blog_categories`.

Its not throwing a error. Tried using echo mysql_error() on it but nothing. It simply acts like a dead link and refreshes the page.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Blog.php:**

```
 function delete($table, $id) {
        $table = mysql_real_escape_string($table);
        $id = (int) $id;

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM {$table} WHERE id = {$id}");
    }
```

**Linking delete function by:**

```
<a href="delete_category.php?id=<?php echo $category['id']; ?>">Delete</a>
```

**Delete_category.php**

```
<?php
include("../script/dbconnect.php");
include("../script/blog.php");

if ( ! isset($_GET['id']) ) {
header('location: cms.php');
die();
}

delete('blog_categories', $_GET['id']);

header('location:category_list.php');
die();
?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: is there an error thrown?

Comment: **a)** you need to use absolute url in header **b)** use of mysql_* function are deprecated in php 5.5 o use either pdo or mysqli

Comment: Did you already simply `echo` the resulting statement?

Comment: Do not use the `mysql_*` functions in your code. These functions are no longer maintained and will be deprecated for good in PHP 5.5. Instead, you should use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Don't know which to use? [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should help.

Comment: Its not throwing a error. Tried using echo mysql_error() on it but nothing. It simply acts like a dead link and refreshes the page.

Comment: Are you sure the link's href attribute is generated correctly? Try to go to the generated link by entering url in address bar. Does it work?

Comment: @ Ivil yeah it does the same thing and doesn't delete the entry.

Comment: try to add 'var_dump($id); die();' in delete() function and check whether you get the id. if not, try to to rename the function to "delete_category"

Comment: @NullPointer Relative URLs in redirects are supported by all browsers, and next version of HTTP spec will make them officially allowed.

Comment: @Barmar would you mind tell me any official source ... so that i can make my mind agree.. i doesn't mean i am disagree with you ..just want to confirm

Comment: @NullPointer http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-21#section-8.1.2

Comment: There are other user agents besides browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, this isn't a complete *answer*, but the comment fields are way, way too short to point you in the right troubleshooting direction.

Your code is broken, but not in the way you might expect.

1. GET requests [*have to be*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) be [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).  That is, they can't have side effects other than serving content.  By having your delete functionality tied to a GET request, you are causing a side effect.  This has some pretty severe consequences.  Some browsers and caching mechanisms can pre-fetch links, for example.  Also think about what a search spider would end up doing if it crawled that page.

   Turn that GET into a POST.  Perhaps use a form and a button instead?
2. It's awesome that you're using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), but your use of it here is incorrect.  `mres` is designed to encode character data as part of a string.  You are using it on an *identifier* -- a table name.  Identifiers do not share the same escaping semantics as strings, especially when used outside of quotes.

   As long as the first argument to the `delete` function never comes through users, you can skip `mres` here.
3. You aren't checking the result from [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query).  Sayeth the manual:

   > For other type of SQL statements, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `DROP`, etc, mysql_query() returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on error.

   You're throwing away the result.  You should check that it *isn't* `false` and then call [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows) to make sure that one and only one row was removed.  If `mysql_query` *was* `false`, then you can check `mysql_error`.

After making these changes, you then need to alter your delete_category.php script to assist in troubleshooting:

1. Add the following two lines to the very top:

   ```
     error_reporting(-1);
     ini_set('display_errors', true);
   ```
2. Change all of the `header`s to `echo`s.  An immediate redirect is going to mask any errors.
3. Use `exit` instead of `die`.  While they do the same thing, the use of `die` is frequently used exclusively in the context of "something went so wrong that I have to exit now," vs `exit`, which is just, well, uh... exit.

Anything that's actually going wrong should then be pretty darn obvious.

If you still aren't seeing anything incorrect happen, and the rows still aren't being deleted, try adding a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` before and after the delete, using the same table name and `WHERE` clause.  That will help us troubleshoot further.

Long term, you really want to begin switching from `mysql_` [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).  The next major release of PHP, version 5.5, is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions.

Comment: Great response, Thanks Charles!